# script tag text/babel variable scope

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Firstly, I understand `text/babel` is not for use in production, but I found it quite useful for development as when I make a change to my `.jsx` file django's dev webserver will reload without me having to do anything (i.e. compile the JSX to JS after every change).

I am not in control of the build environment (e.g. django) as this is a small plugin for a larger system that I am not developing.

The problem is this:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="{% static "myapp/js/main.jsx" %}"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
      console.log(mything);
    }
</script>
```

Where `mything` is in `main.jsx`, something as simple as:

```
var mything = "hello";
```

If `main.jsx` is javascript (and the type of the script tags is changed accordingly) then this will work just fine. As `text/babel` though, it will not work because `mything` is not in scope.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mything is not defined
```

This makes sense to me as I wouldn't expect script tags of different types to share a scope, but I'm wondering if there is some clever way around this to aid development?

I previously had all the code in a single `text/babel` block, but as it grows, it would be nice to separate it out into several JSX files.

Comment: For completeness. I ended up removing the use of `text/babel` and instead building my code with webpack.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without diving too deeply into the Babel source (looking at https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel/src/api/browser.js), I'm going to guess that it reads your JSX source, performs transformation on the source, and then `eval`s the source in some way to execute it. The scope is not shared because babel prepends `'use strict';` to the transformed code (standard in ES6).

If you really need to expose a variable, you can attach it to `window` (ie use `window.mything` in your JSX instead of just `mything`). Ideally, you should make use of modules as you split your code up into multiple files. You can make use of a build step to transform your code through Babel and use browserify/webpack to manage dependencies.

Comment: I have basically never used eval so wasn't aware of how "use strict" affected it. That's interesting.

Comment: As for the rest. Yes, I know about modules, but this is a trivialised example.

I can't really add a build step as I'm not in control of the build system and I don't want to have to collaborate with people who don't have my local build setup where they are modifying the javascript when the real source is JSX. There isn't really a clean solution to that in the long term, so that is probably what I will have to go with.

Comment: I see. In that case, very carefully adding objects to the global scope from your JSX files seems like a viable solution.

Comment: Link is not working!