# How will my React.render function access external javascript file containing react code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Hello React!</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
var GoodbyeWorld = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
       <div>
        GoodBye World
        </div>
      );
  }

});
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
        Hello World
        <GoodbyeWorld />
         </div>);
    }
});
  ReactDOM.render(
    <HelloWorld />,
    document.getElementById('example')
  );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

Hello World

GoodBye world

When I cut and paste my **var GoodbyeWorld** into an external javascript file(saved in the same folder called goodbye.js) and change my code to the following, I do not get the desired output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Hello React!</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example"></div>
<script src="goodbye.js" type="text/babel"></script>
<script type="text/babel>
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
                <div>
                    Hello World
                    <GoodbyeWorld />
                </div>);
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('example'));

 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Is there another way for my inline script that has react code to know that the code it has to call is in a external javascript?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109430/script-tag-text-babel-variable-scope

Comment: Checked the question now, mines the same.. My apologies

Answer (score 1):

You have to expose the GoodbyeWorld var in the end of the goodbye.js file:

```
window.GoodbyeWorld = GoodbyeWorld;
```

It happens because browser babel transpiler uses the "use strict;", which enforces private scoping.

Anyway, `babel browser` and `text/babel` are just for testing purposes. I suggest using webpack with babel transpiler (to compile and bundle your js files before deploying or in the fly with "hot" reload) and the `import`/`require` pattern for modularity.

Comment: Using webpack with babel seems like an efficient solution, I will learn how to do that. Found a link:  https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html
Thankyou