# Import Classes to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, class, module

I'm working on an AngularJS project and I'm responsible to do the frontend and we got to the part where we need to merge everything.

The backend is done using Classes like the following *User.js*:

```
import Text from "./text";
export default class User {
    constructor(id, username, password, firstName, lastName, texts) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.texts = texts;
    }
}
```

so I included it on *Index.html* like this:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="src/user.js"></script>
```

and I want to use the addText method in a service called *TextService* and, following the backend example I was provided, i'm doing it like this:

```
angular.module('moduleName').controller('AppLoginCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.login = function(username, password){
                var user = new User(0, "username", "1234", "Name", "Surname");
    };
}]);
```

This, however, throws the following error:

> ReferenceError: User is not defined
>       at n.$scope.login (//localhost/teste/js/controllers/AppLoginCtrl.js:7:23)
>       at fn (eval at  (//localhost/teste/libs/angular/angular.min.js:212:346),
>   :4:416)
>       at f (//localhost/teste/libs/angular/angular.min.js:252:418)
>       at n.$eval (//localhost/teste/libs/angular/angular.min.js:133:39)
>       at n.$apply (//localhost/teste/libs/angular/angular.min.js:133:269)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (//localhost/teste/libs/angular/angular.min.js:252:470)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.n.event.dispatch (//localhost/teste/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js:3:6404)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (//localhost/teste/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js:3:3179)

Am I missing something? The person responsible for doing the backend also doesn't know and I couldn't find any sollution following multiple examples when googling it.

Comment: I don't know anything about babel, maybe a scope issue, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109430/script-tag-text-babel-variable-scope

Comment: unfortunatly it didnt solve anything :(

Comment: Object._addTex.. Seems like something is bound to Object instead to User. This might be due to common problem of scope in JS.  Somewhere in chain of functions this got switched to Object. Might be in here? addText_IDB(text, function (result) {
            call(result);
        });

Comment: Anyway I think you cannot port your backend code to your frontend without some edition. Remove all the `export`/`import` stuff as you are now sourcing your files with `<script>` and AngularJS does not manage components.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith changed the code sample and error due to some confusion of mine. The addtext part was irrelevant since User was unknown when calling the constructor at first. ring any bell the way i put it now? :(

Comment: @RaphaMex removed the import and export from user.js but still same error, perhaps i didnt undertood correctly what you meant ? hmm